# Inserting Data into listView from database

Tags: android, listview

I want to start an app with just one button called "Add New User" and one textView titled "No User Added" in the MainActivity... and then after adding a new user, I want to add that user's name in a ListView removing the textView "No User Added" in the MainActivity... How do I proceed??Please help me

Comment: Well then, did you have any code just yet? any XML files created for your activity?

Comment: yes I have created my registration code+xml,main activity code+xml

Answer (score 0):

Create an ArrayList that contains text "No User Added" and set that as the ListView data. Then have a setOnClickListener for the "Add New User" Button. Do the process for creating a new user, add that new user data into the ArrayList, and then update the ListView data.

Ex:

```
ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
userList.add("No User Added");

// add data in custom adapter
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.the_row, userList);
ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.the_row);
dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

// Button onClickListener
AddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Update ArrayList with new User
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Done this once, check out my code-(Here **DataHandler** is the class file which manages the database)-

```
    public class HistoryPage extends Fragment
{
DataHandler handler;
int i,num;
String nm1,nm2,result;
private ListView mainListView ;  
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
View v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, container,false);
    ActionBar bar=((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setTitle("History");
    bar.show();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mainListView = (ListView)v.findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
    handler=new DataHandler(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    handler.open();
    Cursor c=handler.returnData();
    c.moveToFirst();
    num=c.getCount();
    String[] Results = new String[num];
    for(i=0 ; i<num ; i++)
    {
        nm1=c.getString(0).toString();
        nm2=c.getString(1).toString();
        result=c.getString(2).toString();
        Results[i]=nm1+" & "+nm2+" - "+result;
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    handler.close();
    ArrayList<String> hstry = new ArrayList<String>();
    hstry.addAll(Arrays.asList(Results));
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.textv,hstry);
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
    return v;
}
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) 
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.clear, menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.cc:handler=new DataHandler(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                     handler.open();
                     handler.removeall();
                     listAdapter.clear();
                     break;
        case R.id.Back_d:getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}